# RabbitMQ with docker-compose is not restoring data

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I want to use rabbitMQ, for this I'm using this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
    - /tmp_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq
```

it works as expected.

I'm entering some users over the admin GUI interface.

But when i delete the container, I was expecting to still have the created users.

But it seems, that rabbitMQ is not saving it in the folder I specified.
I was going through the documentation, but i haven't found any other folder where this configurations are saved

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need these three volumes which include all configs, and you need to add one more `ENV`:

```
environment:
    - RABBITMQ_NODENAME: MYNODE@rabbitmq  
volumes:
    - ./rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    - ./definitions.json:/opt/definitions.json
    - ./rabbitmq.config:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

see [this](https://github.com/dockerfile/rabbitmq/issues/22)